# How do I convert the following Linear Programming Problem into a word problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, word-problem

Maximize $$z=2x_1+10x_2+15x_3$$
Subject to :
$$\begin{align}
3x_1+x_2+5x_3&\le55\\
2x_1+x_2+x_3&\le26\\
x_1+x_2+3x_3&\le30\\
5x_1+2x_2+4x_3&\le57
\end{align}$$
With non-negetivity constraints :
$$x_1,x_2,x_3\ge0$$

Comment: Are you just looking for any possible scenario to fit this LP?

Comment: It would be preferable if it were related to economics and the constraints were resource constraints. But any other scenario would be great too. I'm really in a fix.

Comment: I've given a classic, "farmer-type" scenario, let me know if it is acceptable. This type of interpretation could be ported to any number of industries.

Answer (score 3):

A farmer has $55$ kg of fertilizer, $26$ kg of pesticide, $30$ kg mulch, and $57$ days worth of labor. The farmer intends on growing wheat, corn, and barley. For every square kilometer of wheat, the farmer must use $3$ kg of fertilizer, $2$ kg of pesticide, a kg of mulch, and $5$ days of labor. For corn, it requires $1$,$1$,$1$,$2$...etc., At the end of the season, every square kilometer of wheat can be sold for \$$2$ thousand, corn for \$$10$ thousand, and barley for \$$15$ thousand. How many square kilometers of each type of plant should the farmer grow to maximize his revenue?

An added benefit of this particular interpretation is it is reasonable to assume that the decision variables can be (approximately) continuous.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @AnurabhChakravarty not a problem! When in doubt, for math programming problems, I immediately go to farmers, scheduling/staffing, or chemical mixing. They tend to yield very 'textbook' and overly simple problems, but for the sake of tests/quizzes they often suffice.

Comment: Do you teach mathematics?

Comment: @AnurabhChakravarty I'm in my last year of an operations research PhD program so I get stuck teaching courses from time to time.

Comment: I'm an undergrad student.

Comment: @AnurabhChakravarty best of luck in your studies! If you ever have a question on OR related material, please feel free to contact me here at math.SE and I will help if I'm able.

Comment: Thanks again for your offer. I always have questions. You'll soon tire of them. I'll only be asking the one's which really perplex me.

Comment: Hi David.  Could you tell me how many intersections will the system of inequalities have? How do we find that?

Comment: @anurabhchakravarty In general, you are describing a standard problem called the Vertex enumeration problem (for polytopes). There are several algorithms for this. I am a bit busy today so I'm unsure if I'll be able to provide more details, but searching that problem should send you in the right direction.